# How remove hashtag and reload page in angular 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing

When im going  to reload  page on this "`http://localhost:55139/#/Loginpath`" using

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true})
```

it working.And when im going to set `useHash: false` than # removed and page working but when im refresh this page with control+F5 its gives Error page not found.

Comment: is it related caching issue?

Comment: no its not caching issue i have checked

Answer (score 0):

This may due to data about location is not stored. We have to use HashLocationSatergy for this.

**HashLocationStrategy** is a LocationStrategy used to configure the Location service to represent its state in the hash fragment of the browser's URL.

For instance, if you call location.go('/foo'), the browser's URL will become example.com#/foo.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html

But while using this you will have the hash tag in the url (as you said in the question)

Comment: i have used HashLocationStrategy ,reload page working for selecting url and press enter ..it refresh the page but on url i have seen # tag thats i want to remove.And when i have removed by using "useHash: false" it is working but at that time when im going to reload page with selecting url and press enter it gives error "resource not found"

Comment: I think without hash tag this reloading issue will not be solved.

Comment: Is this possible to replace # with any other character?

Comment: Right now # is there if you want you can make index.html# or someword#